# Write unittest case if a method or function returns array or list?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here the question is that how to write test case for a Model mothod or function who returns an array or list?

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    # function to split tags
    def tag_list(self):
        taglist = self.tags.split(',')
        return taglist
```

Here `tag_list` is that function who returns list of tags

Here i am expecting to write a unittest case for `tag_list` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Unit Test in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002079/how-to-write-unit-test-in-django)

Comment: @Dmitry I have written the correct answer of this question thanks for your kind efforts, wishing you a merry christmas in advance

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution of this question, you can write test case for such function or method like this, inside `test_model.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase
from Api.models import *

class TaskModelTest(TestCase):
    def test_tags_list(self):
        title = "Task Name"
        desc = "Description"
        tags = "a,b"

        task = Task.objects.create(title="Task Name", desc="Description", tags="a,b")
        self.assertEqual(task.tag_list(), ['a', 'b'])
```

Implement it carefully, don't give extra spaces in tags between comma separated values